# Redirect output to two unnamed pipe Linux

Tags: bash

I would like to do this in a bash script:

```
tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log > $pipe1 AND $pipe2
```

where `$pipe` are two unnamed pipes. I know it can be done using `tee` command but I could not get it to work.

Comment: You can try with:
`tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log | tee >($pipe1) >($pipe2)`

Comment: @AvihooMamka I think that would actually split output three ways: to pipe1, pipe2, and to stdout (tee always passes to stdout as well). So the line should perhaps read `tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log | tee >($pipe1)` **`>`** `>($pipe2)` (tee only gets one argument, and stdout is redirected to pipe2).

Comment: In terminal `tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log | tee >($pipe1) >($pipe2)` redirect it to itself. and `tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log | tee >($pipe1) > >($pipe2)` does not work at all. in script I get `permission denied`??

Comment: Alternative approach - since `/var/log/kern.log` is produced by syslog, are you in a position to reconfigure syslog to produce the extra output files?

Comment: @Toby Right now, it works if I do not want to use `tee`. I mean I have to open that file for both of them. But I would like to know how would be your approach?

Comment: Can't  you simply use `tail ... | tee "$pipe1" "$pipe2"` without all the redirection stuff? `tee` accepts multiple files as output.

Comment: @ManuelBarbe Yes that is exactly what they should do.

Comment: I can get it work by this command : `tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log | tee $(echo $pipe1 && echo $pipe2)` , but it has output for stdout as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
tail -n0 -F /var/log/kern.log | tee "$pipe1" "$pipe2" >/dev/null
```

The `tee` output is being redirected to `/dev/null` and is prevented it to be printed on terminal.